# Share a Python Script as exe or in virtual env

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, packaging

I need to share a script with end users who do not know python. I can share the script either as an exe or a zip with dependencies. Users wouldn't know to install packages. Can you please advise me the best method to do this. I am fine to create a virtual env and share the same with end users. Please provide some reference.

I tried pyinstaller by the exe doesn't run and exits with error version.json not found wcwidth. Tried installing the package and still the issue persists.

Any help at the earliest is much appreciated.

Comment: Well you can double-click on the file from your file explorer. I can't speak for macOS, but in windows, you can set default application to open with, and after that double clicking will run the program. Even if you don't set the default program, i still think it will work

Comment: If you don't want to have to install any Python packages, you could try Docker: https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-python-application. The end users would need to also install Docker and your Docker image. Using Docker should also solve compatibility issues.